# Looking for a short story where humans kidnapped by aliens live in a simulation

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

Looking for a short story where a group of humans are stuck in a game like simulation, they break out of the simulation only to find that they were in hibernation and playing the game to pass time.

However the plot twist is that they're actually astronauts who were kidnapped by aliens, and the reason why their simulation is so game like is because the aliens made it based on the video games the astronauts played.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Sounds like "Jewels in an Angel's Wing" by Ian Watson. Please check out this Q&A and let us know if that's the one you're looking for. https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/86354/sci-fi-short-story-soul-stealing-space-snakes

Comment: That's the one, thank you very much!